# Does RDi convert RPG fixed form code to free form?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg, rational-developer-for-i

In RDi, am looking to refactor some RPG code and right clicked on fixed definition of field, then 'Convert Selection To Free-Form'. Would you expect this action to convert the field definition to a free-form definition. I get a 'Conversion complete' message but nothing happens to the selected code.

Tried searching RDi help for this action but couldn't find anything that provides a clear answer. Google turned up [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21675905) and [this](https://archive.midrange.com/wdsci-l/201510/msg00141.html). Who knew you could do that with RPG IV book has [this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FXGpDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA361&dq=RDi%20RPG%20convert%20selection%20to%20free%20form&pg=PA361#v=onepage&q=RDi%20RPG%20convert%20selection%20to%20free%20form&f=false).

Comment: Did you actually "select" any source lines? I.e., what did the "selection" consist of?

Comment: Yes, selected just the field and the entire line but neither worked. Although, both received "conversion complete" message. No error messages appeared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RDi's fixed to free form converter only works on code (c-specs).

It's also just a very basic converter, for example it doesn't convert MOVE to EVAL.

If you want a more full function converter, take a look at [Linoma's RPG Toolbox](http://www.linomasoftware.com/products/rpg-toolbox) or [Arcad's Transformer](https://arcadsoftware.com/products/arcad-transformer-ibm-i-refactoring-tools/)

There's also [Craig Rutledge's](http://www.jcrcmds.com/index.html) open source conversion tools.

Answer (score 0):

These days there is a very nice converter packaged as a [VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BrianJGarland.vscode-rpgfree). It had been a standalone online app called rpgfreeweb, but that has been taken down. You can still [host it yourself](https://github.com/worksofbarry/rpgfreeweb) (i.e. run it locally) if you want.

People who program on IBM i but don't have RDi would do well to take a look at [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [Code for IBM i](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HalcyonTechLtd.code-for-ibmi) extension. It's not as full-featured as RDi, but it's pretty impressive (and arguably better than RDi in some respects), and it's completely free.